# POST/DELETE API not working in live environment (Nextjs Vercel), but working on local

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, vercel

This is my first post. I am new to nextjs and I have created a CRUD app with it with mongodbAtlas. The app runs perfect locally. However when I deploy my app in Vercel, an error keeps appearing when I POST/EDIT/DELETE a post. For GET routes, it seems fine. I suspect since I am using getserverprops/getstaticprops for all my GET routes, I dont have to use the fetch api since getserverprops/getstaticprops is already in the backend. Hence I am able to go through that route without any issues. However with POST/EDIT/DELETE, i am require to use the fetch api and I encountered the issue below with the following error message.

"Unexpected end of JSON input"

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at 851-34a77e046c2b77ce.js:1:8410
at s (main-a02e7d4f7d70ed47.js:1:87663)
at Generator._invoke (main-a02e7d4f7d70ed47.js:1:87451)
at Generator.P.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (main-a02e7d4f7d70ed47.js:1:88086)
at F (851-34a77e046c2b77ce.js:1:5610)
at i (851-34a77e046c2b77ce.js:1:5813) undefined 'Unexpected end of JSON input'
```

When I look into the Vercel logs. this is the error message I got:

```
2022-04-20T00:25:08.652Z    52c2dbff-2d42-42e6-9ef0-580f18b74b93    ERROR   Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:534:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
at Object.5865 (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/products/[id].js:244:39)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/server/webpack-api-runtime.js:25:42)
at __webpack_exec__ (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/products/[id].js:570:39)
at /var/task/.next/server/pages/api/products/[id].js:571:28 {code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', 
path: '/var/task/node_modules/next/package.json', requestPath: 'next'}
RequestId: 52c2dbff-2d42-42e6-9ef0-580f18b74b93 
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

For my post route, this is my code for fetching a POST route:

```
    try {
      const addProductToDBResponse = await fetch("/api/products/createProduct", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "same-origin",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      const addProductToDBStatus = await addProductToDBResponse.json();
      if (addProductToDBResponse.status === 201) {
        setImageUrl([]);
        setIsLoading(false);
        await router.push(`/products/${addProductToDBStatus.newProductId}`);
        alertService.success(addProductToDBStatus.message, { keepAfterRouteChange: true });
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
        await router.push("/products/addProduct");
        alertService.error(`${addProductToDBStatus.message}: ${addProductToDBStatus.body}`, { autoClose: false, keepAfterRouteChange: false });
      }
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log(e, e.data, e.message);
    }
```

This is my API route for different request:

```
  try {
switch (req.method) {
  case "GET":
    if (id === "getAllProducts") {
      return getAllProduct();
    } else {
      return getOneProduct(id as string);
    }
  case "POST":
    if (session?.role === "admin") {
      return createProduct(req, res);
    }
  case "PUT":
    if (session?.role === "admin") {
      return editProduct(req, res);
    }
  case "DELETE":
    if (session?.role === "admin") {
      return deleteProduct(req, res);
    }
  default:
    return res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
}
} catch (e) {
console.log(e);
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help out. I have been wrecking my head for the past few days. If you need any additional information, please reach out and i will post it up. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the POST `/api/products/createProduct` request being made from? Can you also show us the full code for the `/api/products/createProduct` file?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves, thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it. However I have solved the the issue after looking through my api routes again. The main issue here was because I merged specific api request routes such as edit (which require Id) with general ones (get all products) into one file. For some reason it worked in my local server but failed in deployment. To rectify that, I split the routes up and create a dynamic route for the edit/delete paths. After that it worked properly. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Glad you made it work. You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.

Comment: noted. I will do that. thanks again!